# Retrieving "Active" state CSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to retrieve the `:active` state CSS with jQuery? The reason why I ask this is because I'm trying to make dynamic code so I don't have to always tweak the jQuery when stylizing an element.

**Edit**

To elaborate, I don't want to `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` because the class might not be the same for every element being affected by my jQuery code.

**Edit 2**

Let me further explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to create a plugin for my own personal use, and instead of having to tweak the code every time I have a new element that will be affected by the plugin, I want it to grab what's already in the CSS so I won't have to lose time. What I'm trying to do is create a button with an `:active` state, and when the user clicks the button, it will "freeze" at that state (my thoughts are to grab the CSS from that state and put them in the `.css()` command). Now, the reason why I don't want to `.addClass()` or `removeClass()` because the `:active` state is going to differ from one button to another.

Comment: If using jQuery, why not define relevant CSS and just `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to apply CSS rules.

Comment: Because that's not dynamic. I'll have to add classes and what if that's not the same for every element?

Comment: It is unclear what your question means then.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the rules of the `:active` pseudo-selector? That seems like a fragile solution to whatever problem you're having.

Comment: The `:active` state of what element(s)? Under what circumstances, in response to what event(s)?

Comment: Clarified it further, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Sooo much better when you describe what you're actually trying to do.  You can read a given CSS rule (if you know exactly what rule you're looking for) and you can get the style that is active for a given object, but I'm not aware of how you'd find a `:active` CSS rule that applies to a given element.  If you know what style properties you're looking to save, you can probably just use jQuery `.css()` to request those specific properties and save their values away.

Comment: Yeah sorry for my horrible mark up from the get go, still trying to figure out how stack overflow really works. Thanks for being patient with me :-p

Comment: still a bizarre concept.. still  haven't really explained why you can't toggle classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo classes such as `:active` cannot be retrieved and manipulated from jQuery. Instead of trying to get this work, I have a workaround to solve this problem.

First create a style container with only the `:active` part. For example:

```
<style id="activeLink">
    a:active { color: #f00; }
</style>
```

Now you can manipulate this using the jQuery, to retrieve current styles

```
var curStyle = $("#activeLink").html();
```

To modify the style

```
$("#activeLink").html("a:active { color: #000; }");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.somebutton').click(function(){
    $(this).css({...}) //insert whatever css
});
```